# How to show text and value on Listpreference list

Tags: android, string, listpreference

I'm trying to show the Listpreference list with both assigned arrays.  Arrays look something like this.

level_array

```
     <item name="level1">Level  1 -   Hi-Score: </item>
     <item name="level2">Level  2 -   Hi-Score: </item>
```

value_array

```
     <item name="level1">5</item>
     <item name="level2">10</item>
```

when I call the listpreference, I'd like it to show both strings combined.  Is this possible?

IE would show list like this

### LIST TITLE

### Level 1 - Hiscore 5

### Level 2 - Hiscore 10

etc.

Secondary question, I'm guessing the value_array values are changeable via code so I can store different values there later?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ListPreference, use something like this

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Weather"
    android:summary="You can simulate the weather"
    android:key="listPref"
    android:entries="@array/level_array"
    android:entryValues="@array/value_array" />
```

Is you want change your xml, I think there won't be a problem

Comment: Yea, that's how I'm defining the listpreference, but it only shows the android:entries values in the listpreference, I would like to show both the :entries and the :entryValues on each line.

Comment: entryValues it is the value of which you use, after click to your entries

Comment: use only level_array. Something like this

Comment: <item name="level1">Level  1 -   Hi-Score: 5 </item>
 <item name="level2">Level  2 -   Hi-Score: 10 </item>

Comment: And then change your level_array

Comment: So you're suggesting I use and change only level_array to show the hi-scores?  The only problem with that is I now have to parse the level_array value to compare hi-scores, which I'm not sure how to approach with java/xml, especially with arrays.